# Refer current executing assembly config settings

Tags: c#, app-config

I am trying to read the connection string value from the current executing assembly's config settings-

```
public static string ConnectionString
{
    get
    {
        string path = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(path);

        return config.ConnectionStrings["DBCon"].ToString();
    }
}
```

I am getting below error which says-

> 'ConfigurationElement.this[ConfigurationProperty]' is inaccessible due
>   to it's protection level

[image]

Any help on this?

Comment: Try this string key_value = refconfig.ConnectionStrings["key_name"].Value;

Comment: @GaurangDave What is `refconfig`?

Comment: object of Configuration. OR try this : string dbConStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbCon"].ConnectionString;  Please make sure that connection string is there under connectionstring section in config file.

Comment: @GaurangDave Please read my question carefully. There is a reason why I am not doing this. `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` refers to the initial start project not the current executing project.

Comment: string path = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(path);

string value = config.AppSettings.Settings["Key"].Value;

Comment: did this solution work?

Comment: @GaurangDave No. I request you not to google and copy paste as I already tried those. Please try it at your end if something works and post it. That would help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
return config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["DBCon"].ToString();
```

`config.ConnectionStrings` returns a `ConnectionStringsSection` object which is public but whose elements `[string]`are internal. However `ConnectionStringsSection` has a public `ConnectionStrings` property which is a `ConnectionStringSettingsCollection` object whose elements `[string]` are public.